# c# can't open form from class

Tags: c#, forms

Please help me with my problem. I have a class in my app. named Aster.cs
Here its source:

```
public class Aster
{
   public static void manager_Events(object sender, ManagerEvent e)
    {
        Global.info = (NewStateEvent)e;
        if (Global.info.ChannelState == "6")

        {
            Global.WMP.controls.stop();


        }
        if (Global.info.ChannelState == "4" || Global.info.ChannelState == "5")
        {
            if (Global.zvonok_window == 0)
            {
                Global.WMP = new WindowsMediaPlayer();
                //Global.WMP.settings.volume = 100;
                //Global.WMP.URL = @"Resources\Ring.mp3";
                //Global.WMP.controls.play();
                Global.zvonok_window = 1;
                Form_calls f = new Form_calls();
                f.TopLevel = true;
                f.TopMost = true;
                f.Location = new Point(0, 0);
                f.Size = new Size(233, 290);
                f.Show();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I've got manager_Events() in some another part of application (when it starts):

```
Global.manager.NewState += new NewStateEventHandler(Aster.manager_Events);
```

The problem is: when I'm trying to open a new form, it's initializing, but freezes and I can't do anything, even close it. I know, that the problem is somewhere in my calling the form from class, but I can't understand what i'm doing wrong. And when i call ShowDialog() method, all works fine. Some part of Form_calls source:

```
public Form_calls()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        this.Show();
        MessageBox.Show("wds");

    }
```

Design does't matter here, i just want to open new form.

Comment: It sounds as though your mixing logic in with design here.. what are you trying to achieve? (there shouldn't be any need to open a form other than from another form)

Comment: If `manager_Events()` isn't called from the UI thread, things will go awry.

Comment: Design doesn't matter here. I just want to open a new form when some event happens in Aster.cs. manager_Events() called from the UI thread/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the  `this.Show();` call from the constructor - you call the `Show` method in `manager_events` later on anyway (and there it is the correct place).

Comment: it doesn't help, the form freezes anyway.